# How to subtract 30 minutes from a date

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

I am getting date value date: 2013-06-07 18:30:00 +0000. I am trying to subtract 30 minutes from this, but it not giving proper time.

I've tried this

```
 NSTimeInterval secondsPerHour = 60*30;
 NSDate *newDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-secondsPerHour];
```

Answer (score 7):

**Reason** : The `negative` of a `unsigned int` is a `positive number`. This should work:

```
NSDate *newDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(NSTimeInterval)((u_int32_t)30*60)];
```

**EDIT** : Alternative use `NSDateComponents`.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setMinute:-30];
NSDate *halfHourAgo = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:yourDateHere options:0];
NSLog(@"\ncurrentDate: %@ \n halfHourAgo: %@", yourDateHere, halfHourAgo);
```

Answer (score 4):

in Swift 5

```
let minus30Min = Date().addingTimeInterval(-30 * 60)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
NSDate *minusOneHr = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-30*60];
```

Comment: I think this is same as the code given in the question. Just toggled the value's places

Comment: read carefully questions then comment,user want to substract minute so it does'n  depends on how many day in month undersatnd tofa ?????

Answer (score 1):

You could try [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html), something like that:

```
NSDate* yourDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]; // your date, to substract 30 mins

NSDateComponents *dc = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:yourDate];
[dc setMinute:[dc minute] - 30];

NSDate* date  = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dc]; // 30 mins before now
```

Or that:

```
NSDate* yourDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]; // your date, to substract 30 mins

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setMinute:-30];

NSDate* date  = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:yourDate options:0]; // 30 mins before now
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste this code in viewDidLoad and check the results first.

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Today %@", today);
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setMinute:-30]; // If you want to change Month,Year,Day,Hour etc. Just change the "setMinute" to setMonth,setYear,setDay,setHour
    NSDate *dateComp = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];
    NSLog(@"Desired Day %@", dateComp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateMinusThirtyMinutes = Date().subtract(30.minutes)
```